# how to add possibilities in a select using f.input :object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, input, collections

I have a form and I want the user to select one of the object.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Promo do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :user
    end
    f.actions
  end  
end
```

Ok, it works, but now I want to add a possibility "All" in the select like this, I tried different things

```
f.input :user + "All"

f.input :user, as: :select, collection: [:user, "All"]
```

But of course, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the collection of objects in :user to inject 'All' in it.

```
@user_names = User.pluck(:name) #or whatever you want to have in your select

f.input(:user, as: :select, collection: @user_names + ['All'])
```